# Docusign - The envelope specified either does not exist or you have no rights to it. - Error thrown with Gmail

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am receiving this error 'The envelope specified either does not exist or you have no rights to it.' when I click to sign a Document that was sent to a gmail account. This only happens when I first click on 'Review Document'. If I close the tab and click again on 'Review Document' I am able to sign the Document. This is happening in my Salesforce Sandbox with gmail accounts. If I use the company email I have no issues.

I have tried with another corporate account and it doesn't throw an error but tried with 1 other public email and still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you're having this difficulty with the DocuSign system.

For help on this type of problem, please contact our support department: https://support.docusign.com/contactSupport

StackOverflow is for developers' questions. 
Many thanks.